# Assign a custom material property to models

Tags: python, materials, scripting, custom-properties

I need an explanation how to access and iterate over Materials in Objects.
I want to add few Custom Properties in a set of files (I want to import each file, add Properties to every material in that model, then export and move to another file).

I've found this reference https://docs.blender.org/api/3.6/bpy.props.html, but I cannot figure out how it works with Materials, code in there doesn't seem to add anything in Material Custom Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've found it out.
I've looped over materials, attach a new property to material by passing property name in square brackets just after the iterator, then assign a new value.

```py
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    mat["prop1"] = "value1"
    mat["prop2"] = [1, 2.3, 16,726]
```

I haven't tried it with multiple objects being present on scene, maybe it will work as well there.